# How do I achieve one by one message delivery for each user individually (in parallel)?

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I need a queue/message broker that would allow me to receive by 1 message for each user.

Previously I've been using FIFO SQS and each user has its own **message group id**, which allows me to have 1 message inflight for each user.
[image: diagram]

But I've ended up with a problem when I have more than 20.000 messages in the queue, because *A FIFO queue looks through the first 20k messages to determine available message groups*, which makes all messages above the 20.000 limit to be unavailable for processing.

Do you guys have any advice for a message broker/queue that would allow me to achieve the same behavior without having a limit of 20.000 messages?

I was thinking about using Redis Lists (where each user has its own list and I do an `RPOP` for each existent list)

Comment: There are 2 main problems with this question. First, asking for "advice" is inherently opinion-based which is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. Second, asking a question across a range of unique software (e.g. Redis, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, Amazon SQS, etc.) is also off-topic. The question is simply too broad. Consider 2 answers, one which provides great advice for Redis and another for RabbitMQ. Which one is "correct"? Stack Overflow is designed for clear, concise questions about programming which elicit fact-based answers. Unfortunately, this question doesn't fit that description.

Answer (score 1):

A couple options to overcome the consumer window problem you describe in ActiveMQ:

1. Use Virtual Topics and have consumers register a selector. The broker will filter messages to each consumer into their own queue. This does not require any broker changes and is completely dynamic via the client setting the selector.
2. Use Composite Destinations to filter messages to separate queues. This is static broker routing and requires server-side config change for any new routing rules. The clients do not need to be changed

Both approaches documented here:
ref: https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations